# img with border-radius overlays its border

Tags: webkit, border, css

In webkit if I set border radius on an image that has a border, the image won't sit nicely within the border but overlay the border and remains square.

http://jsfiddle.net/ECNJ4/

Any fixes that don't mean using a background image instead or adding markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out: http://jsfiddle.net/ECNJ4/6/

**CSS**

```
img {
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 16px red;
}
```

​

Answer (score 0):

I had to use a wrapper element around the img to make it work. Maybe there's a better solution, but I didn't find it.